# How to get the height of an element in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

How to get the height of an element in reactjs for use it in a style of another element ?

What is wrong in my code ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

class Messages extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            height: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const height = this.input.clientHeight;
        this.setState({ height: height });
    }

    render() {
        const outputStyle = {
            overflowY:'scroll',
            height:`calc(100%-${this.state.height})`
        };

        const inputStyle = {
            position:'fixed',
            bottom:'0',
            height:'auto'
        };

        return (
            <div style={{height:'100%'}}>
                <div name="output" style={outputStyle}/>
                <TextField name="input" multiLine={true} fullWidth={true} underlineShow={false} style={inputStyle} rows={2} ref={(input) => {this.input = input;}} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Messages;
```

My objective is to define the height of the element "output" by this way : 100% - this.state.height.

Comment: calling `this.state` after `setState` would still give you the initial value. try log.console inside the render method. to see the value of the state

Comment: Try `this.setState({ height: height }, () => { console.log(this.state.height) });` and see what this gonna log

Comment: i got "undefined" in log

Comment: thats because this.input.clientHeight may be undefined

Comment: `this.input.clientHeight` where is this coming from?

Comment: <TextField name="input" multiLine={true} fullWidth={true} underlineShow={false} style={inputStyle} rows={2} ref={(input) => {this.input = input;}} />

Answer (score 1):

a ref on a custom component returns the component instance, not a dom node

I have to use: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.input).clientHeight;

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous, your state will properly update somehow after the call. Then render will be called again. Try checking your new state in render or in componentWillUpdate : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate

You should never look for a change in your state right after changing your state.

Just set your outputStyle.height to this.state.height and you should be good.

Comment: in render, i got "undefined"